# Is there a way to make the user use a parameter from a predefined set?

Tags: c#, list, methods, parameters

I was wondering if it was possible if i could make the method force you to either use something out of a set list.

Example of what im trying to do:

```cs
public static List<string> languages = new List<string>() { "cs", "de", "en", "es", "fr", "it", "jp", "nl", "ru", "zh" };

// Im trying to enforce the translate() method to make the parameter "transTo" one of the strings in the 
// list. I might be dumb and new but is this possible in c#?

public static void Translate(string path, string key, string transTo)
{
   ...
}
```

Quite new to stack overflow, tell me what i've done wrong `:I`

Comment: Are the contents of the `languages` list determined at compile time or run time? E.g. is it possible to add languages to the list and thereby make a new language code valid?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use of an Enum:

```
enum LanguageCode
{
   cs,
   de,
   en
}
```

and then accept the enum:

```
public static void Translate(string path, string key, LanguageCode languageCode)
{
   ...
}
```

and then of course the calling of the method:

```
Translate(path, myKey, LanguageCode.cs);
```

even better: you can use either descriptions or a dictionary to make the selection more friendly, but meet your internal requirements as well:

```
public enum Language
{       
    English,
    Japanese,
    Spanish
}

private Dictionary<Language, string> LanguageMap = new Dictionary<Language, string>()
{
    {Language.English, "es"},
    {Language.Japanese, "jp"},
    {Language.Spanish, "es"}
}
```

and then interally, it would be used as:

```
 callExternalApi(stringToTranslate, LanguageMap[languageCode]);
```

Comment: This is a good answer, a word of warning. Enums in C# aren't very strict. They're essentially integers with some type checking information. I could cast any `int` to a `Language` value and it would be valid. So while this pattern encourages developers to use one of the defined values for `Language`, you should still check that the value you got passed in is one of those values, possibly with [Enum.IsDefined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @JoeSewell agreed, and like most things there are cool things you can also do because of exactly this. Like avoiding a navigation property for a type table lookup.